# How to get hexbin center coordinates?

Tags: r, ggplot2, hexagonal-tiles

```
library(hexbin)
x <- rnorm(mean=1.5, 5000)
y <- rnorm(mean=1.6, 5000)
bin<-hexbin(x, y)
plot(bin@xcm, bin@ycm, pch=20)
```

I want to get the center coordinate of each hex in a hexbin plot. But xcm and ycm are not the centers of the hexagons as shown in the above example.

[image]

How to get the center coordinate of the hexagon? Two solutions are needed one for hexbin package, one for ggplot2.

Comment: How many bins do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `hcell2xy` to extract the center co-ordinates of the hex bins. It returns a list with x and y components, so can be plotted directly:

```r
library(hexbin)

set.seed(1)

x   <- rnorm(mean = 1.5, 5000)
y   <- rnorm(mean = 1.6, 5000)

bin <- hexbin(x, y, xbins = 30)

plot(bin)
```

[image]

```r
plot(hcell2xy(bin))
```

[image]

In fact, the `hcell2xy` is what `ggplot` uses internally to get its points (inside the unexported function `ggplot2:::hexBinSummarise`

<sup>Created on 2022-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For ggplot2 try this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

hex_plot <- tibble(
  x = rnorm(mean = 1.5, 5000),
  y = rnorm(mean = 1.6, 5000)
) |>
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_hex(binwidth = 1)

hex_coords <- ggplot_build(hex_plot)$data[[1]] |> 
  tibble() |> 
  select(x, y)

hex_plot + 
  geom_point(colour = "white", data = hex_coords)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>